# nodejs getting raw https request and response

Tags: node.js

i was in the process of answering this question

[Retrieving the http.ServerResponse body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826524/retrieving-the-http-serverresponse-body)

im trying to capture the raw string of an https request and response, for http it works fine

```
    var http = require('http');
    var util = require('util');
    
    var req,res;
    
    var server = http.createServer(onrequest);
    
    server.listen(81);

    server.on('connection',socket=>{
    
          console.log('***   connection   ***');
          
          req   = '';
          res   = '';
          
          socket.on('data',data=>{

                req  += data.toString();

          });
          
          var write   =   socket.write

          socket.write=function(data,encoding,callback){

                res  += data.toString();
  
                write.apply(socket,arguments);

          }//write
    
    });
  
    function onrequest(request,response){

          console.log('*** request : '+request.url+' ***');
          
          response.on('finish',()=>{
          
                console.log('---   request   ---');
                console.log('['+req+']');
                console.log();
                console.log('---   response   ---');
                console.log('['+res+']');
                
          });
          
          request.on('data',data=>{});

          request.on('end',()=>response.end('Hi.  This is my http response.'));

    }//onresquest
```

simplifying things using a single curl request

```
curl http://localhost:81/
```

gives the required data, congrats i thought onto my project and .. nope

when using https with the following code

```
    var key; // = .....
    var cert; // = ....
    
    var server = https.createServer({key,cert},onrequest);
```

and again using curl

```
curl -k https://localhost:81/
```

no data is logged, the problem is this

on the connection event the socket passed is of type "socket" presumably a net.socket

the socket that is passed to the onrequest function is of type "tlssocket"

so i thought maybe i could use the underlying "duplex" which they do both share, however when i try to add the on data event to the duplex, with either

```
//on connection
var duplex = socket.__proto__;
duplex.on('data',data=>{
```

or

```
duplex.on.call(duplex,'data',data=>
```

it fails at [Node.js JavaScript runtime](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/streams/readable.js#L888)

does anybody know how to get further than this?

related questions :

[Get raw HTTP response in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70367660/get-raw-http-response-in-nodejs)

[How can I get the raw HTTP message body using the request library in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334503/how-can-i-get-the-raw-http-message-body-using-the-request-library-in-node-js/73510277#73510277)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey dokey

the solution is to use the "secureConnection" event, like so :

```
var https = require('https');

var req,res;

var key;    // = ...
var cert;   // = ...

var server = https.createServer({key,cert},onrequest);

server.listen(81);

server.on('secureConnection',socket=>{

      console.log('***   connection   ***');
      
      req   = '';
      res   = '';
      
      socket.on('data',data=>{

            req  += data.toString();

      });
      
      var write   =   socket.write

      socket.write=function(data,encoding,callback){

            res  += data.toString();

            write.apply(socket,arguments);

      }//write

});


function onrequest(request,response){

      console.log('*** request : '+request.url+' ***');
      
      response.on('finish',()=>{
      
            console.log('---   request   ---');
            console.log('['+req+']');
            console.log();
            console.log('---   response   ---');
            console.log('['+res+']');
            
      });
      
      request.on('data',data=>{});

      request.on('end',()=>response.end('Hi.  This is my http response.'));

}//onresquest
```

this can be seen implemented

[github: simple-server - no dependencies](https://github.com/javascript-2020/simple-server)